# Can you use a list (or other collection) to specify what messages to receive in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

E.g. suppose I have a list that looks something roughly like this:

```
Handlers = [{foo, FooHandler}, {bar, BarHandler} | Etc()]
```

The best that I can come up with is this:

```
receive
  Message ->
    Handler = find_matching_handler(Message, Handlers),
    Handler(Message)
end
```

The problem with this is that if Message does not match anything in Handlers, it's too late: I've taken it out of the mailbox.

I guess if there's a way to put a message back into the mailbox (into the save queue) *without reordering*, then that would take care of it. Simply resending to self() would reorder. It would also not restart the receive, and even if it did, you might get stuck in a spin loop until a message of interest arrives. Is there a way to put a message into the mailbox's save queue?

Another near solution that I thought of was to use match guard, but IIUC, you can only use BIFs in guards, which seems to preclude using find_matching_handler (unless there is a BIF for that).

Another near solution: map matching:

```
receive
  M when Handlers#{M := Handler} -> Handler(M)  % booyah?
end
```

Alas, I have not found an incantation that satisfies Erlang...

Answer (score 0):

Match on the message:

```
loop() ->
  receive
    {foo, Data} ->
      handle_foo(Data),
      loop();
    {bar, Data} ->
      handle_bar(Data),
      loop()
  end.
```

This is the basic way of distinguishing between message forms.

You can also be less direct and match in a function head you pass all messages to:

```
loop() ->
  receive
    Message ->
      handle_message(Message),
      loop()
  end.

handle_message({foo, Data}) ->
  foo(Data),
  ok;
handle_message({bar, Data}) ->
  bar(Data),
  ok.
```

A combination of the first and second forms is sort of the way gen_server type callback modules are structured in OTP. The message handlers receive a slightly more complex set of arguments and exist in their own module (the part you write), and the actual `receive` occurs in the generic gen_server module.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question: the list is not static. Imagine you are given an ARBITRARY list of the form given in the question (that's why there's an Etc() there), and the _same_ code must be able to handle such a list. Your second suggestion ignores the requirement that non-matching messages do not get removed from the mailbox, or that any removed message needs to be put back in the same position.

Comment: @allyourcode This is the bullet train to madness. You might want to think hard about why you think you need this. Unexpected messages are usually matched by a `receive ... Other -> log(Other) end` sort of clause at the end and *should not be handled* because unknown mysterious processes should not be sending random mysterious messages through your system. If you want to be able to register an event handler at runtime use gen_event (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html) or write your own similar thing. You'll find fitting use cases of that module to be rather narrow for a reason.

Comment: Just because you cannot imagine how this could be useful does not mean that it's crazy. The messages are not unexpected; the set of expected messages is specified dynamically in a list, rather than statically in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **selective receive** pattern to periodcally scan the mailbox for handler messages. Something like this:

```
check_msg_handlers(Handlers) ->
  [check_handler(X) || X <- Handlers],
  timer:sleep(500),
  check_msg_handlers(Handlers).

check_handler(Handler) ->
  receive 
    {_Handler={M,F}, Msg} ->
      M:F(Msg)
  after 
    0 ->
      no_msg
  end.
```

Note the `receive X -> Y after -> N no_msg end`, this is the selective receive. When using a timeout of `N=0` it effectively becomes a scan of the mailbox to see if the `X` message is present or not, i.e. it becomes a non-blocking receive. The order of the messages is preserved after the scan as required in your case.

The LYSE chapter [More On Multiprocessing](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing) has a section on selective receives that is very good.